# Django fields not being removed from forms

Tags: django, forms, field

I have a form defined as the following:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm as DjangoUserCreationForm

class UserEmailForm(DjangoUserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email",)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserEmailForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

but when I try to display the form, it shows four fields, username, email, password1, password2

Answer (score 0):

these fields are defined in the UserCreationForm form, Meta#fields doesnt affect them

Comment: Shoud I redefine them in the subclass then?

Comment: maybe you dont need UserCreationForm since you want to get rid of these fields. isn't ModelForm enough? where you can exclude whatever you want